# How to extract the last substring using JavaScript regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regular expressions. I am trying to use JavaScript regular expressions to extract the last substring within parentheses from a string. It's not working for me. Instead, I'm getting the first substring within a pair of parentheses. Can someone help me?

Here's an example. I am trying to extract the substring 'xyz', but instead I'm getting 'abc'.

```
var str1 = 'Hello World (abc)'; // May or may not contain parentheses
var str2 = '(xyz)'; // Definitely contains parentheses
var troublesomeString = str1 + ' ' + str2; // This is the string I'm working with

var result = myFunc(troublesomeString);
alert(result); // Should say 'xyz', but instead says 'abc'

...

function myFunc(troublesomeString) {
    // Here I am trying to get '(xyz)', but am instead getting '(abc) (xyz)'
    var resultArray = troublesomeString.match(/\(.+\)$/);
    troublesomeString = resultArray[0];

    // Here I am trying to get 'xyz', but am instead getting 'abc'
    resultArray = troublesomeString.match(/[a-z]+/); // Adding a $ after + doesn't help
    troublesomeString = resultArray[0]; // resultArray[1] is null

    return troublesomeString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are matching everything in between the first "(" and the last ")" which must end the string.

Try this instead to match the contents of the last set of parentheses (which still must end the string as per the '$'):

```
var resultArray = troublesomeString.match(/\([^)]+\)$/);
```

Comment: @hawaiijim Feel free to mark it answered then. ;) ...and you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

#### First try

You need to add `\(` and `\)`:

```
resultArray = troublesomeString.match(/\([a-z]+\)$/);
```

And the result is `["(xyz)"]`, Note the `$` there.

#### Last try

If you want to `group` out something, you should wrap `()` to them :

```
resultArray = troublesomeString.match(/\(([a-z]+)\)$/);
```

Note the `( )` pair.

the result is `["(xyz)", "xyz"]`

And you know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex instead of the first regex you are using: `/\([^\(]+\)$/`.  The `^\(` tells it to accept any character except a `(`.

As a note, you can use this site http://regexpal.com/ to help you build and test regular expressions.

Comment: This solution works too. It does seem that you don't need to escape the parenthesis when it's preceded by ^

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "g" switch to perform a global search.

Here's a working example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = "test (abc) (xyz)";
    var result = str.match(/\([^)]+\)/g);

    alert(result[result.length - 1]);
</script>
```

Comment: Careful. If no matches are found then *result* will be `null`, attempting to read the *length* property of *null* will throw an error, so test it first: `alert(result && result[result.length - 1]);`

Comment: In my case the last set of parentheses is guaranteed to exist, so this solution works. Since I need a second regex to remove the parentheses anyhow, the "g" switch doesn't add any benefit (or cause any harm) over Shadow Creeper's similar solution. It was nice to learn how the "g" switch works, though.

Comment: Actually, I think there is a potential benefit to the "g" switch. Unlike when using $, using the "g" switch means the close parenthesis doesn't need to be the very last character in the string. In my case it will be the last character, but it's good to learn how to parse other strings from right to left.